# Proving existence of a smooth map with a given condition

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $p\in M$. Let $V$ be a $n-$dimensional subspace of $T_pM$.
In this case is there a smooth map $F:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow M$ such that it maps origin to $p$ and $F_\ast$ maps the tangent space at the origin to $V$ isomorphically?

Comment: hint:  use charts

Comment: @JasonDeVito Could you explain little bit more? Thank you.

Comment: Well, can you solve the problem if $M=\mathbb{R}^k$?

Comment: @JasonDeVito Is $F$ a map that sends every point to $p$?

Comment: @JasonDeVito Could we first define a map on a neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^k$?

Comment: For your first comment, a constant map always has 0 differential.  For your second, don't you want the domain to be $\mathbb{R}^n$?  Also, you may want to further simplify the problem and assume $p=0$.